# why shell 'join' command lost some correct results

Tags: shell, join

When I use 'join' to merge two sorted files, the result is unexpected.
here is the example:

//file a.bat

```
12
123
456
13421
123456
```

//file b.bat

```
12
123
5432
123456
```

execute the command:

```
$ join -1 1 -2 1 -o '1.1 2.1' a.dat b.dat  
12 12
123 123
```

where 123456 is ignored! In fact, i did try other files, some of them also didn't get full results. why did it happen?

Comment: I almost got the answer, I used 'sort -n' for sorting, which is for numeric. but join command only works for string ordered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input needs to be lexically sorted in order for `join` to work correctly. Your input is numerically sorted, which is wrong. All strings which start with 1 should be before all strings which start with 2, etc.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks! join use string compare when merging two files